# Why can't i push new data into the json in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am using node js and mongoose to register a new user and i have used jwt token. But i can't add token field to json when trying like this.

```
const user  = require('../model/user')
.
.
.

 var userInfo = user({
        email: req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password,

    });

    const token = jwt.sign({user_id: userInfo._id, userInfo.email},
        process.env.TOKEN_KEY,
        {
            expiresIn: "1h",
        });

userInfo.token = token;
console.log(userInfo);
```

But this token can't be pushed to userInfo.
Initially userInfo would be like this

```
userInfo = {
"email":"a@b.com",
"password": "hahaha",
}

Expected output is 
userInfo = {
"email":"a@b.com",
"password": "hahaha",
"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiNjEwNTUwY2YyYzUwMWQ0NTA5YmFmOTIw"
}
```

But actual output is still

```
userInfo = {
"email":"a@b.com",
"password": "hahaha",
}
```

The problem is simple (Please ignore variable spelling or sth that's not the issue) but i can't push new data to userInfo.

Comment: Please remove `c` tag. Tag it `nodejs`

Comment: what is the value of process.env.TOKEN_KEY ? (if you want to keep it secret, tel us what is its length)

Comment: your misunderstanding the concept of jwt, you don't need to store it anywhere serverside

Comment: length of TOKEN_KEY is 13. I think its not a problem here. The same problem came when i tried to push new data that i obtained from find() query.

Comment: Yes i might not need to store it in db. But i might need to insert new filed in json.